# insert data into datagridview in form2 from form1

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to add data into form2 from form1 but my code isnt working, each time run it gives the error "row index is out of range, parameter name row index"
What am I doing wrong Please

```
Public Sub Create_View()
        Dim BillnAddress As Object = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select [BillingAddress] From Customers Where [CustomerID] = '" & CustomerComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString & "'", PayrollHome.Con).ExecuteScalar
        Dim ItemName As String
        Dim ItemCode As Object
        Dim ItemDescription As Object
        Dim Qty As Integer
        Dim UnitPrice As Integer
        Dim TotalPrice As Double
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            With DataGridView1.Rows(i)
                ItemName = DataGridView1.Item("Product", i).Value.ToString
                ItemCode = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select [Item Code] From [Inventory Items] Where [Item Name] = '" & ItemName & "'", PayrollHome.Con).ExecuteScalar
                ItemDescription = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select [Description] From [Inventory Items] Where [Item Name] = '" & ItemName & "'", PayrollHome.Con).ExecuteScalar
                Qty = Val(DataGridView1.Item("Quantity", i).Value)
                UnitPrice = Val(DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value)
                TotalPrice = Val(DataGridView1.Item("Line_Total", i).Value)
                SalesInvoice.DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Qty, ItemCode, ItemName, ItemDescription, UnitPrice, TotalPrice)
            End With
        Next
        '
        SalesInvoice.InvoiceNoLabel.Text = ReferenceTextBox.Text
        SalesInvoice.InvoiceDateLabel.Text = InvoiceDatePicker.Value
        SalesInvoice.CustomerIDLabel.Text = CustomerComboBox.SelectedValue
        SalesInvoice.BillingAddressBox.Text = BillnAddress
        SalesInvoice.DueDateBox.Text = DueDateTimePicker.Value
        SalesInvoice.OurOrderBox.Text = OrderTextBox.Text
        SalesInvoice.SalesRepBox.Text = RepComboBox.SelectedValue
        SalesInvoice.TotalBox.Text = FormatNumber(GrandTotalTextBox.Text, 2)
    End Sub



Private sub View_invoice() Handles Button1.click
    Create_view
    SalesInvoice.show
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to review the [DataGridViewRowCollection.Insert Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.insert?view=netcore-3.1) … from what I can see, the method requires a row index to know what position at which to insert the row. Otherwise, use `DataGridView.Rows.Add(..)`

Comment: If you'd just keep your data in a DataTable and pass that round, like Microsoft intended you to, your life would get a lot easier

Comment: @JohnG Exact! I used the answer below and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not clear if you want to add a row or to insert a row in a specific index.
However take a look how is made add or insert a row (and see differences with your code):

```
 SalesInvoice.DataGridView1.Rows.Add({Qty, ItemCode, ItemName, ItemDescription, UnitPrice, TotalPrice})
 'OR 
 Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
 SalesInvoice.DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(rowIndex, {Qty, ItemCode, ItemName, ItemDescription, UnitPrice, TotalPrice})
```

Comment: Thanks Man. I Used the second option and it worked perfectly. If you know how much headache this stuff gave me. Thanks alot